# Do you need to allocate memory before assigning one pointer to the other?

Tags: c

I am trying to understand two things. What is meant by overwriting a malloced memory. Would the following be considered as overwriting since I am assigning B to A.  Is allocating memory for B really necessary ?. If one were to do it is it considered a bad practice ?.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    typedef struct {
        int data;
    }somestruct;

    somestruct *A,*B;
    A = malloc(sizeof(somestruct));
    B = malloc(sizeof(somestruct));

    B = A;

    return 0;
}
```

Consider this piece of code.  Am I overwriting the memory when assign the value of a to b. In this case I have to allocate memory for b unlike the previous case where the code works if I do not allocate memory for b. Can somebody explain 1. Am I overwriting memory here. 2. Is it always required to allocate memory for both pointers when assigning (equating) one to the other.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int i=0;
    int *a=malloc(sizeof(int)*10);
    int *b=malloc(sizeof(int)*10);

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        a[i]=1;
    }

    for(i=0;i<10;i++){
        b[i]=a[i];
        printf("%d\n",b[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't really want to answer because there are two different questions here. Please edit and ask a single question.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not required. You shouldn't cause memory leak.

Do not forget to `free()` everything you created via `malloc()`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{

    typedef struct {
        int data;
    }somestruct;

    somestruct *A,*B;
    A = malloc(sizeof(somestruct));
    /* do not do this because this cause memory leak */
    /* B = malloc(sizeof(somestruct)); */

    B = A;

    free(A); /* do not forget to free the memory */
    return 0;
}
```

In the second code, you are using both buffers whose addresses are assigned to `a` and `b`, so both `malloc()` are required. Again, do not forget to `free()` everything you created via `malloc()`!

Comment: Can you please expand what do you mean by using both buffers in the second case. If I were to equate members of the structures in the first case would I be using both buffers then ?

Answer (score 1):

In the first example: No need to malloc memory for B.
The next statement make it point to the memory allocated for A.
It's perfectly normal for 2 pointers to point to the same place in memory.

In the second: it makes sense. There you copy the values from the memory allocated for A, to the memory allocated for B.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely not, in fact, allocating memory to B (and then subsequently losing the only pointer to it by assigning A to it) will cause a memory leak in your code. You do not want memory leaks in your code.

Conclusion: No, its unnecessary and bad to do so.